# EF Code First - ConcurrencyCheck and optimistic concurrency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency

Is it possible to write a method that takes current context, then tries to save changes to it, but if it fails, it is refreshing values from db and applies changes once again?
I have this:

```
private static void SaveChanges(ScykDb context)
{
    var savedChanges = false;
    while (!savedChanges)
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
            savedChanges = true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            objContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ex.Entries.Select(e => e.Entity));

        }
    }
}
```

But all it does is either apply pre-modified values or leave data untouched (depends on `RefreshMode`). I would like this code to take data from database, and then apply changes to it. It probably is not possible, but i am curious about it.

Comment: Are you sure the values in ex.Entries contain the values you want to update?

Comment: But then you'd effectively kill the purpose of optimistic concurrency. Shouldn't you at least check whether any changed properties override changes made in the mean time?